# Jquery slideToggle help!

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

**Is there any other way to do slide toggle, couse in IE7 does´t work!?**

*$(document).ready(function() {

$(".tela").hide();

```
   $("li.menu-pai").click(function(){           
      $(this).show().next().slideToggle("fast"); 
 });
```

})*

```
<div id="menu_sidebar">
     <ul>
        <li class="menu-pai"><a href="#">Iltem</a></li>        
            <ul class="tela">
                <li><a href="#">sub-item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub-item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub-item</a></li>
                </ul>      
        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try put ul inside li

```
<div id="menu_sidebar">
     <ul>
        <li class="menu-pai"><a href="#">Iltem</a>
            <ul class="tela">
               <li><a href="#">sub-item</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">sub-item</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">sub-item</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li>Other Item</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

and call

```
$("#menu_sidebar li.menu-pai a").click(function(){
   $(this).find('ul').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

I don't know if this is going to work.

And don't use show/hide methods if you use slide, call .slideUp(0); at start.

Comment: Very good, it' working fine.
Your way to put all ul block inside the li, is good.